# How to send custom error mesage with node.js for http status codes

Tags: node.js, react-native, react-redux

I am working on a rest-based api using node.js for user authentication.  I would like to send a custom error message more descriptive like "Incorrect username/password combination".  On the presentation side, I have react-native using fetch and redux-saga.

Here is the redux-saga code for sending the username/password to the rest layer and receiving the http error message returned:

```
export const login = ({userName, password}) => {
    return fetch(globals.BASE_URL + `/api/login`, {
        method  : 'POST',
        headers : {
            'Accept'        : 'application/json',
            'Content-Type'  : 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            userName: userName,
            password: password
        })
    });
}

const fetchLoginStatus = function* (action) {
    const response = yield call(login, action);

    try {
        if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
            const userInfo = yield response.json();

            yield put({type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, authToken: userInfo.authToken});
        } else {
            yield put({type: ERROR_MESSAGE_OCCURRED, errorMessage: response.statusText});
        }
    } catch (error) {
        yield put({type: ERROR_MESSAGE_OCCURRED, errorMessage: error});
    }
}
```

Here is the node.js code for returning the error message:

```
app.use(function (err: Error, req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) {
if (err instanceof IncorrectLoginError) {
    //Tried this approach initially, did not work either
    //res.statusMessage = err.message;
    //res.status(400).end();

    res.status(400).json({
        error: err.message
    });
} else {
    return res.end();
}
});
```

Here is the issue, when I run the debugger from the emulator and I check the response object returned from the fetch call, I keep getting the following in the response object:

```
Response {
        type: 'default',
            status: 400,
            ok: false,
            statusText: undefined,
            headers:
        Headers {
            map:
            { 'x-frame-options': [Object],
                'strict-transport-security': [Object],
                connection: [Object],
                'x-dns-prefetch-control': [Object],
                date: [Object],
                'x-content-type-options': [Object],
                'content-length': [Object],
                'x-download-options': [Object],
                vary: [Object],
                'x-xss-protection': [Object],
                'content-type': [Object] } },
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/login',
            _bodyInit: 'Bad Request',
            _bodyText: 'Bad Request' }
```

Ultimately, I would like to set the statusText that goes with the statusCode but that is not working.  For the second approach, I tried to pass an error string with the return object, but looking at the Response object, that is not working either.  What is the correct way to set the statusText that accompanies the statusCode?

Here is the error message displayed when I run from "Test RESTful Web Services" on Web Storm:

[image]

Comment: is ur error an err instanceof IncorrectLoginError ? Have you verified it ?

Comment: Yes, when I try from the "Test RESTful Web Services" tool from the webstorm api, I see the error message display in the response Tab.

Comment: Can you add the error message to the question ?

Comment: Yes, the instance is correct.